# Listen events in iframe by parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to trigger this event:

```
$("body").trigger({
                type: 'Edge_Plantilla_ClosePopup',
                sym: sym,
                evt: e
            });
```

and the element is on an iframe with a random id.

In parent i'm listening the event like:

```
$("body").on("Edge_Plantilla_ClosePopup", function (evt) {
        play_buttons();
        close_popup();
        console.log("close");
    });
```

But it's doing nothing. I'm pretty sure that is something about the iframe but idk how can I listen the trigger.

EDIT:

This is my project: 
Main:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFkeA.png

Child:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6I1W.png

EDIT:

**I just found a solution!**

parent.html

```
$(document).on('Edge_Plantilla_ClosePopup', function(e) {
      //etc.
});
```

iframe.html

```
parent.$(parent.document).trigger({
                    type: 'Edge_Plantilla_ClosePopup',
                    sym: sym,
                    evt: e
                });
```

and it's working correctly. The trick is to just use the jquery from the parent

Comment: Events are occurring in 2 different windows . Could use postMessage API

Comment: Fastest thing I can think about: put that listener on the Iframe's page and let it fire a function on its parent. But only if you have control over the content in the child.

Comment: Is it necessary that u use IFRAME ? iframe is bad, ask internet ;)

Comment: I know, I hate them too but it's not optional

Comment: @GunBlade You should accept caeth's answer. Although he wasn't specific as to where to place the code it was his code nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
parent.$("body").trigger({
            type: 'Edge_Plantilla_ClosePopup',
            sym: sym,
            evt: e
        });
```

Comment: I tried that but it's doing nothing yet. When I do this parent.$("body").html(""); it works so I can't understand what it's happening

Comment: @GunBlade I think caeth forgot to tell you that his code must be on the child page. So naturally you would have seen nothing happen if you used his code on the parent page. To make everyone's life easier there is certain information you should always mention when your question concerns an iframe:

Comment: 1. You should include the location of the child page. Is it in the same directory as the parent page? Or is it on another domain?          2. Do you have access to the child page?   3. Are you attempting any transferring of files through your iframe? It's important to be aware of certain filetypes that browsers will not accept through an iframe like rss, vtt, xml unless you take certain measures that usually involve access to your server.

Comment: I have access to the code of both sides and yes, I include the code on my child frame. The child and the father page are in the same domain but not in the same folder